# Positioning Multiple labeled equations in minipage

Tags: equations, minipage

I have been playing around with minipage to fit 3 equations on the same line. I want all equations to be individually labelled and on the same line but as the leftmost equation starts too far in the rightmost equation is pushed off the page. I would like to replicate the second image below but keep getting the first. I have tried flushleft and \centred but they did not help.

[image: What I am getting.]
[image: What I would like]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \section{Equations}

    \noindent\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
        \begin{equation}
          T = \frac{F}{bh} \label{1}
        \end{equation}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
        \begin{equation}
           S = \frac{\epsilon}{l} \label{2}
        \end{equation}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
        \begin{equation}
             E = \frac{V_c}{h} \label{3}
        \end{equation}
    \end{minipage}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You have three minipages that each is half the width of the text block next to each other, so naturally the last one pokes into the right margin. Try `0.33\linewidth` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0.5 times three is 1.5, so the three minipages next to each other is 1.5 times as wide as the text block. Use `0.33\linewidth` instead for the `minipage` widths.

You might also want a bit of space after the `minipage`s, for example a `\medskip`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\begin{document}
\section{Equations}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
    \begin{equation}
      T = \frac{F}{bh} \label{1}
    \end{equation}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
    \begin{equation}
       S = \frac{\epsilon}{l} \label{2}
    \end{equation}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
    \begin{equation}
         E = \frac{V_c}{h} \label{3}
    \end{equation}
\end{minipage}

\medskip

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: can we force `yshift`  to the label (for  `(1)`)?

Comment: @alper You want to move the equation number up or down? Don't know, try searching, or post a new question if you can't find any other questions about that.

Comment: Yes sir I wanted to move it up litte bit up inside the minipage.